# Is there a way to 'mimic' another OS from Windows 7 to get a driver / application to install?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, compatibility

I recently bought a HP Officejet 6500, which has the ability scan and fax, besides the default printer functionality.

Howvever, it turns out that the drivers on the CD-ROM and HP website do not support Windows 7. I already tried running the setup.exe in compatibilty mode and I even tried manually installing the .msi packages, with no success.

I am almost certain that there is no actual problem with installing these drivers, as Windows Vista drivers work in almost every case on Windows 7. I am guessing there is simply a hardcoded "block" in the setup file which does not allow me to install the driver.

**Besides running application in compatibility mode, is there any other way to actually trick an application into believing you run another OS?**

Comment: Are you sure you can't get drivers for this from Windows Update?

Comment: Already tried this. Windows update only provides the actual printer drivers, but I also need to be able to use it as a scanner and fax. These HP-utilities are not included in the Windows update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to extract the drivers from the MSI package and force-install the driver via the device manager.

right click the device > update driver software ... > Browse My Computer ... > Let me pick from a list > Have Disk ... > point to the *.inf file you have extracted and ignore any warnings.

before you do that, you may create a drive image of your windows 7 partition, in case something does not go according to your plan.

Comment: You can use Universal Extractor to extract the files : http://legroom.net/software/uniextract.

Comment: good point. make it an answer and earn yourself some karma to burn. :)

Comment: Blue screen in 3...2....1...

Comment: @Molly - answer posted. Note: I actually found Universal Extractor in one of your answers in another post ...

Comment: i'm a sucker for 'portability' so i'm using UE quite frequently. :)

Comment: less MSIerables is another good way to do it, @harrymc . I've had times where MSIerables does it when Universal Extractor wouldn't. Sometimes 7-zip works as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) to extract the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .exe file to install the drivers, you can install in xp mode, I did this on an old sony vaio that didn't have a display driver for 7.  It worked like a charm

Comment: Its worth mentioning that "XP mode" is available only in Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate versions.